# Reversing a string in C without the output being null

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I am trying to reverse a string (character array) using the following code, but when I attempt to print the string, the value of null. This is a homework assignment, but I am trying to learn so any help would be appreciated.

```
void input_reverse_string(const char* inputStr, char* reverseStr)
{
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;

    for (; *(inputStr++) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        length++;
    }

        while (*inputStr)
    {
        *reverseStr = *inputStr;
        inputStr++;
        reverseStr++;
    }

    
    const char* chr_ptr = &inputStr[length - 1];
    printf("I see a %s\n", *chr_ptr);


    *reverseStr = '\0';
    
    printf("%d", length);

    /* return reverseStr; */ 
}
```

Comment: How are you using this function? Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Let's assume that reverseStr points to some allocated memory. after the first `inputStr++` the variable `inputStr` never points to the beginning of the string again.  In fact, at the end of the for loop it points to the ending zero, so the while loop is always skipped.

Comment: The length calculation is very iffy, and that should really be a separate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are out of order:

1. That's a strange way of computing the length of a string. You are using an index variable that you don't need, and incrementing 3 things at the same time, it's unneeded to say the least.
2. After calculating the length, and incrementing the `inputStr` pointer up to its end, you don't reset the pointer, so it still points to the end of the string (actually, one after the end!).
3. Inside the `while` you are advancing both pointers (`inputStr` and `reverseStr`) in the same direction, which can't possibly be right if you want to *reverse* the string.

The correct way to do this would be:

1. Compute the length of the string. Either use `strlen()` or do it by hand, but you really only need to increment *one* variable to do this. You can avoid incrementing `inputStr`, just use a temporary pointer.
2. Start from `inputStr + length` and walk backwards. Either use a pointer and do `--` or just index the string).

Here's a working example:

```c
void reverse_string(const char* inputStr, char* reverseStr) {
    unsigned len = 0;
    int i;

    while (inputStr[len])
        len++;

    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseStr[len - i - 1] = inputStr[i];
    }

    reverseStr[len] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    char a[6] = "hello";
    char b[6];

    reverse_string(a, b);
    puts(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
olleh
```

Comment: Thank you Marco. Do you suggest I use a for loop for step #2? Something like: for (int i = inputStr + length; , i >= 0; i--)?

Comment: @JulieThompson that would be one way to do it, yes. Careful though `int i = lengtht`, not `int i = inputStr + length`.

Comment: Hmm..ok. Good catch. I added the following line after the for loop, but after I submit input, the program 'hangs': printf("%c", inputStr[i]);

Comment: @JulieThompson not sure what's wrong. I've added an example, hope that's clear enough.